# Single Queue or Multiple Queue on Azure, Multiple subscriptions on same topic

Tags: azure, messaging, azure-queues

In my application, we have different type of messages, like failure events, state change events etc. These events can further classified as process failed, machine failed etc. And we have different logic to handle different type of events (Process failed is handled differently and machine failed is handled differently).

As of now we have create multiple Service Bus Topic on main type- one for failure events and another for state change events. And since we can have multiple consumer for same type, we use subscriptions for them. But on consumer side, now we have some consumer that need to listen to both kind of events (like Notification Consumer). But Azure does not allow to have a subscription from multiple topic.

My question, is "Should this notification consumer listen to multiple subscriptions or we should create one more topic (and subscription) and publisher should publish message on multiple topic?"

Logically, Notification consumer should listen to multiple Subscription, But that add complexity when we need to scale this consumer. It will depend on multiple Queue depth.